# How to separate domain and path from URL in C?

Tags: html, c, regex, http

I try to read a URL (which can contains path or does not, e.g. http://google.com and http://www.google.com/abc/dfg) from command line argument, then separate them into domain name and path, but the results seems incorrect, and without valgrind shows no error but valgrind shows errors.
I just cannot figure out how to fix it. Can somebody help? Thanks a lot!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* domain;
    char* path;

    sscanf(argv[1], "http://%[^/]/%[^\n]", domain, path);
    printf("domain: %s\n", domain);
    printf("path: %s\n", path);
}
```

Comment: `scanf` does not allocate the storage for `domain` and `path`. You must pass it valid buffers.

Comment: You could use `strtok` to separate the domain from the path in the string.

Comment: Watch out for `https` too. You check for that first with `strstr` giving a result of `argv[1]`.

Comment: FYI: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/parseurl.html

Comment: So will I malloc at the beginning work? But I do not know the how long are domain and path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> valgrind shows errors

and it is rigth to do, you missed to initialize *domain* and *path* to a valid (enough) storage

For instance do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char domain[32];
    char path[64];

    sscanf(argv[1], "http://%31[^/]/%63[^\n]", domain, path);
    printf("domain: %s\n", domain);
    printf("path: %s\n", path);
}
```

Note I limited the length to read to not write out of the arrays (I removed 1 in the size to have place for the null character)

But I also encourage you to check *argv* and the value return by *sscanf* to know how much element you read, and to return a value :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char domain[32];
    char path[64];

    if (argc < 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <URL>\n", *argv);
      return -1;
    }

    switch (sscanf(argv[1], "http://%31[^/]/%63[^\n]", domain, path)) {
    case 2:
      printf("path: %s\n", path);
      /* no break */
    case 1:
      printf("domain: %s\n", domain);
      break;
    default:
      fputs("this is not a valid url\n", stderr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

of course you can also initialize *domain[0]* and *path[0]* to 0.

Compilation and executions:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall a.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Usage: ./a.out <URL>
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out aze
this is not a valid url
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out http://google.com
domain: google.com
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out http://google.com/abc/dfg
path: abc/dfg
domain: google.com
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out http://google.com/a_too_long_path_to_be_memorized_in_only_64_characters_so_it_is_cut
path: a_too_long_path_to_be_memorized_in_only_64_characters_so_it_is_
domain: google.com
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note a secure url (*https*) is considered invalid

Comment: I tried your code, but my compilation results still show errors.
==24992== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24992==    at 0x48B9B1A: __vfscanf_internal (vfscanf-internal.c:2471)
==24992==    by 0x48B4471: __isoc99_sscanf (isoc99_sscanf.c:31)
==24992==    by 0x1091A2: main (a.c:9)
==24992==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==24992==    at 0x109169: main (a.c:5)

Comment: @Emmm are you sure you copy it right ? I did some edit, refresh the page and do again. Of course use the second proposal in the answer

Comment: Sorry..I made a mistake. It works now. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: If I need to use pointer instead of arrays to store domain and path, how can I modify the code? Since I do not know how much memory to malloc before sscanf?

Comment: @Emmm by definition domain and path cannot be longer than argv[1], so you can allocate strlen(argv[1]) characters for both

Comment: Thank! Then do I need to add 1 for null byte?

Comment: @Emmm not needed because some characters like *http://* are missing, so you can allocate a little less than *strlen*, but this is a detail